# How to compile ruby from source with debugging symbols on osx?

Tags: ruby, makefile, compilation, rbenv

I'm trying to compile Ruby from source with debugging symbols. I am not using `rbenv` or `rvm`, etc.

I have already tried

> ./configure optflags="-O0" debugflags="-g3 -ggdb"

To no avail :( (the debugger claims it has no symbols)

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I figured it out in the end, you do this:

> CFLAGS="-O0 -ggdb" ./configure

Comment: AFAICS `ruby` defaults to [`-O3`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_6_6/configure.ac#L227) and [`-ggdb3`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_6_6/configure.ac#L655) (which is equivalent to `-g3`). Before finishing `./configure` reports which options it's going to use (`CFLAGS`, `optflags`, `debugflags`). The [latter](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.3.0/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) is fine for debugging, as for the [former](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.3.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) it's best to build with `-Og`. To use that run `./configure optflags=-Og`.

Comment: I was looking for ways to verify it was compiled correctly. You can check if a shared object or binary preserved the symbols with `file $(command -v ruby)` , the output should show "not stripped" when it is preserved and "stripped" when it is not.

I noticed that both with and without those flags it says "not stripped" when compiling from source. Anyone know why, does source default to keeping symbols?

Answer (score 0):

I recently needed to build `ruby` inside a `docker` container. Here's what I did:

`1.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -eux
apk add build-base autoconf bison linux-headers git ruby zlib-dev openssl-dev readline-dev libffi-dev gdbm-dev
git clone https://github.com/ruby/ruby
cd ruby
git checkout v2_6_6
autoconf
./configure optflags=-Og
make install
```

```
$ docker run --rm -itv $PWD:/app alpine:3.11 sh
/ # /app/1.sh
```